# Read values from JSON objects and sum all values into single object using Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I want to add the values "V" from the response objects based on Time's `at`, into single object. We will get different responses with single or more than one objects. For example, the following data has three objects after parsed the response :

```
data = [
  {
    "MeterId"=>"201_12",
    "MeterName"=>"WHr",
    "Values"=> [
      {"at"=>"2015-11-25 01:00:00", "v"=>"90.00"}, 
      {"at"=>"2015-11-25 01:10:00", "v"=>"10.00"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "MeterId"=>202_12",
    "MeterName"=>"WHr",
    "Values"=>[
      {"at"=>"2015-11-25 01:00:00", "v"=>"50.00"}, 
      {"at"=>"2015-11-25 01:10:00", "v"=>"60.00"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "MeterId"=>"203_12",
    "MeterName"=>"WHr",
    "Values"=>[
      {"at"=>"2015-11-25 01:00:00", "v"=>"70.00"}, 
      {"at"=>"2015-11-25 01:10:00", "v"=>"40.00"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Actual Output:

```
#<DataObject:0x00000002e3fee8@parameter="RefPowerSubscription", 
@samples=[
#<DataHash:0x00000002e3fda8 @value="90.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>00=>00", @count=0, @name="">, 
#<DataHash:0x00000002e3fd30 @value="10.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>10=>00", @count=0, @name="">, 
#<DataHash:0x00000002e3fc90 @value="50.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>00=>00", @count=0, @name="">, 
#<DataHash:0x00000002e3fc18 @value="60.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>10=>00", @count=0, @name="">, 
#<DataHash:0x00000002e3fb78 @value="70.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>00=>00", @count=0, @name="">, 
#<DataHash:0x00000002e3fb00 @value="40.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>10=>00", @count=0, @name="">], 
@max=0, @min=0, @sum=0>
```

I need output in this format:

```
#<DataObject:0x00000002eb85f0 @parameter="RefPowerSubscription", 
@samples=[
#<DataHash:0x00000002eb84b0 @value="210.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>00=>00", @count=0, @name="">,
#<DataHash:0x00000002eb8208 @value="110.00", @time_stamp="2015-11-25 01=>10=>00", @count=0, @name="">], 
@max=0, @min=0, @sum=0>
```

This is my code. It is working with one object but I don't know how to handle multiple objects. Here DataObject is class, we are using it to store Hash values.Can anyone help me out with logic?

```
class DataObject
  attr_accessor :count, :samples, :average, :parameter

  def initialize(parameter,sample_size = 0)
    @parameter = parameter
    @samples = []

    sample_size.times do
      @samples << DataHash.new
    end

    @max = 0
    @min = 0
    @sum = 0
  end
end
```

```
class DataHash
  attr_accessor :value, :time_stamp, :count , :name

  def initialize
    @value = 0
    @time_stamp = ''
    @count = 0
    @name = ''
  end
end
```

```
dobj = DataObject.new('RefPowerSubscription')
dhash = DataHash.new
len = data.length

until i == len do 
  data[i]['Values'].each do | data |
    dhash.time_stamp = data['at']
    dhash.value = data['v']
    dobj.samples << dhash.dup
  end

  i += 1
end

p dobj
```

Working Code

```
vtime = Time.parse(stime).to_s
i =0
loop do
value = 0

data.reduce(len) do | memo, temp |

temp['Values'].reduce(temp.size) do | sum , order|
    if Time.parse(vtime) == Time.parse(order['at'])
        value += order['v'].to_i
    end
end

end
dhash.time_stamp = Time.parse(vtime)  # order['at']
dhash.value = value 
dobj.samples[i] = dhash.clone

vtime = (Time.parse(vtime) + 600 ).to_s
i +=1
break if Time.parse(vtime) > Time.parse(etime)
end

p dobj
```

Comment: What is `DataObject`? Please take the time to format your data and code for readability, making sure it's indented correctly. You're asking people to take time to help you, so it's expected you'll take time to help them help you. Please read "[ask]".

Comment: Are you given the JSON as a file?  from a web request?  Have you already parsed into a ruby Hash?

Comment: @roger sorry that is already parsed one.

Comment: Your "code" doesn't remotely produce the output you give. What is a DataObject? A DataHash? What do they do? What exactly do you mean by " It is working with one object but I don't know how to handle multiple objects." ?

Comment: @FélixSaparelli : I have updated the supporting class code, now you will get the output. also i have shared actual and expected output. In this example we have three loops (objects), i want to add all values from 3 objects.

Comment: You want something using [#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

Comment: @FélixSaparelli , Using reduce method I was able to add all the values,but I want to add values based on time. I am able to match first time period only. Can you tel me how to check time for all values.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli .. I got the solution , I have shared the final code. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just put this somewhere there:

```
timestamps_hash = {}

 data.each do |outer|
   outer["Values"].each do |inner|
     if timestamps_hash.key? inner["at"]
       timestamps_hash[inner["at"]] += inner["v"].to_f
     else
       timestamps_hash[inner["at"]] = inner["v"].to_f
     end
   end
 end
```